# iMacros - How to click images by identifying their link?

Tags: image, hyperlink, click, imacros

In a webpage I have multiple images with the same name but each one, when clicked, leading to a different location. So each image has a different link. How do I make iMacros click the images based on their links?

Answer (score 0):

scrape the images href and use it to decide which one do you need, something like this:

```
tag pos=1 type=img attr=href:* extract=href
```